# How to clone generic List<T> without being a reference?

Tags: c#, generics, clone

I have a generic list of objects in C#, and wish to clone the list.

```
List<Student> listStudent1 = new List<Student>();
List<Student> listStudent2 = new List<Student>();
```

I used an extension method is below, but it can not :
(when changes in listStudent2 -> affecting listStudent1)

```
public static List<T> CopyList<T>(this List<T> oldList)
{
    var newList = new List<T>(oldList.Capacity);
    newList.AddRange(oldList);

    return newList;
}
```

I would like to keep adding element or making changes in listStudent2 **without affecting listStudent1**.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do a deep clone. That is to clone the Student objects as well. Otherwise you have two separate lists but both still point to the same students.

You can use Linq within your CopyList method

```
var newList = oldList.Select(o => 
                new Student{
                             id = o.id // Example
                            // Copy all relevant instance variables here
                            }).toList()
```

What you might want to do is make your Student class be able to create a Clone of itself so you can simply use that in the select instead of creating a new student there.

This would look something like:

```
public Student Copy() {
        return new Student {id = this.id, name = this.name};
    }
```

Within your student class.

Then you would simply write

```
var newList = oldList.Select(o => 
                o.Copy()).toList();
```

within your CopyList method.

Comment: Do like this ? 
 `var newList = oldList.Select(o =>
                new Student
                {
                    id = o.id,
                    name = o.name
                }).toList();`
but there was an error.

Comment: I edited my answer now with a method that is actually better since it works with encapsulation. Make a public method Copy inside the Student class that actually Copies/Clones it. Then simply use that method in the select.

That way it can clone private and protected fields.

Comment: Johan: Ok it run well. Thank you very much!